# Changes to List Columns not Updating to Content Type

Tags: content-type, column

I have a document library with a Document Set content type in it. I created a bunch of custom columns in the list, and added them to the document set. I have changed the display name of some of the list columns. However, the Document Set is still using the old names. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Used ContentTypes in List/Libraries are always **copies** of the parent contenttype. You can push changes **down** but not **up** the ContentType tree

Comment: How many document set do have in a library? The one which you have mentioned is that a default content type?

Comment: I just added the default document set type, than added the list columns to it within the list. I think that does create a new content type though, since the GUID for it is not the same as the base document set.

Comment: Yes when you use a content type in a library or list the ID of it changes to what its in Site Content Types. But What ever changes you make in Site content type it should push down.